# Python3 np.cov giving strange result

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, covariance

```py
import numpy as np    

X = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
np.cov(X)

#Results in:
array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])
```

While it should output:

```py
array([[0.66666667, 0.66666667],
       [0.66666667, 0.66666667]])
```

Comment: I think you need to specify the ddof parameter: try `np.cov(X, ddof=0)`. From the documentation: _ddof : int, optional
    If not ``None`` the default value implied by `bias` is overridden.
    Note that ``ddof=1`` will return the unbiased estimate, even if both
    `fweights` and `aweights` are specified, and ``ddof=0`` will return
    the simple average. See the notes for the details. The default value
    is ``None``._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the default `cov` is normalized by `N-1` which is an unbiased estimate. To get simple average you can do either of these solutions:

```
np.cov(X,bias=True)
```

or

```
np.cov(X,ddof=0)
```

output:

```
[[0.66666667 0.66666667]
 [0.66666667 0.66666667]]
```